# How To Return A Function To A Label StringValue

Tags: swift

```
func GetTheTime() {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let date = Date()
    _ = Calendar.current

    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    print("\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
    var theTime = "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
```

How can I call this and have it return and display into a label.StringValue?

Comment: Please read the [Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158) chapter in the Swift book and review the section on return values.

Comment: Don't name your methods starting with an uppercase. Use a `return` (also in the declaration of the method). Don't use `NSCalendar` and all NSStuff in general in Swift when there is equivalent without it (NSCalendar vs Calendar, NSURLRequest vs URLRequest, etc.). And you could have used a `DateFormatter` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return something you add an arrow plus the type of data you'd like returned. Like so:

```
func getTheTime() -> String {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let date = Date()
    _ = Calendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    return "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"
}
```

Then you can use the `getTheTime()` function like a string so you can do this:

```
myLabel.text = getTheTime()
```

If you want it to always show the updated time in seconds you'll have to call a timed function which you can find answers for here on stack overflow.

Comment: Don't use `NSCalendar`. And what's the point of `_ = Calendar.current`?

Comment: The point of this answer was to show how to return a string and use it for the label text. I edited only the necessary parts of his code to show how to achieve what he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 func getTheTime()-> String{

    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
    let time =  "\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)"

    label.text = String(time) //label is the name of your label
```

Or you could use **DateFormatter**